# jq: find unique keys from multiple object

Tags: json, key, distinct, jq

I manage to get the list of keys, but can't make it a list to pass into `unique`.

https://jqplay.org/s/-YDVDeXTHb

I'd like to get a list of zone names, i.e.

```
"asia"
"asia-east"
"asia-northeast"
"asia-south1"
"asia-southeast"
"australia"
"australia-southeast1"
```

I can manually remove "cores", "memory" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An only-jq solution:

```
.gcp_price_list
| del(.sustained_use_base,.sustained_use_tiers)
| [.[] | keys_unsorted[]]
| unique[]
```

(Using `keys_unsorted` here saves unnecessary sorts.)

### Better

The above solution has two main problems:

a) it uses `unique`, which involves an unnecessary (and perhaps undesirable) sorting operation;
b) it includes keys whose values are not numbers and are presumably therefore to be excluded.

The following variation addresses both problems.  For convenience, we define these generic functions:

```
def set(s): reduce s as $x ({}; .[$x | (type[0:1] + tostring)] = $x);

def distinct(s): set(s)[];

.gcp_price_list
| del(.sustained_use_base,.sustained_use_tiers)
| distinct(.[]
           | keys_unsorted[] as $k
           | select( getpath([$k]) | type == "number")
           | $k)
```

This will still include some irrelevant keys, which of course can easily be removed (e.g. using array subtraction).

Answer (score 0):

If you put your JSON data into a file, you can do something like this:

```
cat data.json \
| jq '.gcp_price_list | del(.sustained_use_base,.sustained_use_tiers) | .[] | keys[]' \
| uniq
```

Comment: On my windows machine, end up with the PowerShell command `Get-Content file.txt | Sort-Object -unique`, `uniq` in git bash doesn't work somehow